# YAAI (Yet another any implementation)

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, template, stl, variant-type

I am a C# game developer currently learning C++ and this is my second *big-ish* project (the first one being a [vector implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227716/yavi-yet-another-vector-implementation)).
This time I opted for implementing a mot-a-mot `any` implementation based on the specifications of the ISO/IEC N4830 standard draft.

My objective is to familiarize myself with the modern C++ techniques.

The code can be found on Github. [Here is the link.](https://github.com/TheSica/any/blob/8ed1e1e4d2e6f4ce5441ec5d96d1dbd9fc88b0b8/any/any.h)

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my code.

```cpp
#pragma once
/*
    At any point, an <any> stores one of the following types:
        1. Big types
        2. Small types
        3. Trivial types

    In the 1st case, <any> will dynamically allocate memory on the heap for the object
    In the 2nd case, <any> will store the object inside any itself
    In the 3rd case, <any> will store the object inside any itself and no destructor shall be called for the object. Additionally, the copy and moves will be treated differently
*/
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>

class bad_any_cast : public std::bad_cast
{
    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return "bad_any_cast";
    }
};

constexpr size_t small_space_size = 8 * sizeof(void*);

template<class T>
using any_is_small = std::bool_constant<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>
                                     && sizeof(T) <= small_space_size
                                     && alignof(T) <= alignof(void*)>; // Check if alignment shouldnt be % == 0

enum class any_representation
{
    Small,
    Big,
};

template<class T, class... Args>
void Construct(void* destination, Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    new(destination) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

struct any_big
{
    template <class T>
    static void Destroy(void* target) noexcept
    {
        std::destroy_at(static_cast<T*>(target));

        _aligned_free(target);
    }

    template<class T>
    static void* Copy(const void* source)
    {
        return new T(*static_cast<const T*>(source));
    }

    template<class T>
    static void* Type()
    {
        return (void*)&typeid(T);
    }

    void (*_destroy)(void*);
    void* (*_copy)(const void*);
    void* (*_type)();
};

struct any_small
{
    template <class T>
    static void Destroy(void* target)
    {
        if constexpr (!std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
        {
            std::destroy_at(static_cast<T*>(target));
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    static void Copy(void* destination, const void* what)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
        {
            *static_cast<T*>(destination) = *static_cast<const T*>(what);
        }
        else
        {
            Construct<T>(static_cast<T*>(destination), *static_cast<const T*>(what));
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    static void Move(void* destination, void* what) noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
        {
            *static_cast<T*>(destination) = *static_cast<T*>(what);
        }
        else
        {
            Construct<T>(static_cast<T*>(destination), std::move(*static_cast<T*>(what)));
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    static void* Type()
    {
        return (void*) & typeid(T);
    }

    void (*_destroy)(void*);
    void (*_copy)(void*, const void*);
    void (*_move)(void*, void*);
    void* (*_type)();
};

template<class T>
any_big any_big_obj = { &any_big::Destroy<T>, &any_big::Copy<T>, &any_big::Type<T> };

template<class T>
any_small any_small_obj = { &any_small::Destroy<T>, &any_small::Copy<T>, &any_small::Move<T>, &any_small::Type<T> };

class any
{
public:
    constexpr any() noexcept
        :_storage{},
        _representation{}
    {
    }

    any(const any& other) noexcept
        :_storage{},
        _representation{}
    {
        if (!other.has_value())
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (other._representation)
        {
        case any_representation::Big:
            _storage.big_storage.handler = other._storage.big_storage.handler;
            _storage.big_storage.storage = other._storage.big_storage.handler->_copy(other._storage.big_storage.storage);
            _representation = any_representation::Big;
            break;
        case any_representation::Small:
            _storage.small_storage.handler = other._storage.small_storage.handler;
            other._storage.small_storage.handler->_copy(&_storage.small_storage.storage, &other._storage.small_storage.storage);
            _representation = any_representation::Small;
            break;
        }
    }

    any(any&& other) noexcept
        :_storage{},
        _representation{}
    {
        if (!other.has_value())
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (other._representation)
        {
        case any_representation::Big:
            _storage.big_storage.handler = other._storage.big_storage.handler;
            _storage.big_storage.storage = other._storage.big_storage.storage;
            _representation = any_representation::Big;
            break;
        case any_representation::Small:
            _storage.small_storage.handler = other._storage.small_storage.handler;
            other._storage.small_storage.handler->_move(&_storage.small_storage.storage, &other._storage.small_storage.storage);
            _representation = any_representation::Small;
            break;
        }
    }

    template<class T, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<VT, any> // can use conjunction and negation for short circuit but it's too hard too 
                                                                               && std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>>> // check if VT is a specialization of in_place_type_t
    any(T&& value)
    {
        emplace<VT>(std::forward<T>(value));
    }

    template<class T, class... Args, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>
                                                                                           && std::is_constructible_v<VT, Args...>>>
    explicit any(std::in_place_type_t<T>, Args&&... args)
    {
        emplace<VT>(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }

    template<class T, class U, class...Args, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT> && 
                                                                                                        std::is_constructible_v<VT, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args...>>>
    explicit any(std::in_place_type_t<T>, std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args)
    {
        emplace<VT>(il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    ~any()
    {
        reset();
    }

    any& operator=(const any& rhs)
    {
        any(rhs).swap(*this);

        return *this;
    }

    any& operator=(any&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        any(std::move(rhs)).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<VT, any>
                                                                                && std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>>>
    any& operator=(T&& rhs)
    {
        any tmp(rhs);

        tmp.swap(*this);

        return *this;
    }

    template<class T, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, class... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>
                                                                                             && std::is_constructible_v<VT, Args...>>>
    std::decay_t<T>& emplace(Args&&... args)
    {
        reset();

        return emplace_impl<VT>(any_is_small<T>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<class T, class U, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, class... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>
                                                                                                      && std::is_constructible_v<VT,std::initializer_list<U>&, Args...>>>
    std::decay_t<T>& emplace(std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args)
    {
        reset();

        return emplace_impl<VT>(any_is_small<T>{}, il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void reset() noexcept
    {
        if (!has_value())
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (_representation)
        {
        case any_representation::Big:
            _storage.big_storage.handler->_destroy(_storage.big_storage.storage);
            _storage.big_storage.handler = nullptr;
            break;
        case any_representation::Small:
            _storage.small_storage.handler->_destroy(&_storage.small_storage.storage);
            _storage.small_storage.handler = nullptr;
            break;
        }
    }

    void swap(any& rhs) noexcept
    {
        any tmp;
        tmp._storage = rhs._storage;
        tmp._representation = rhs._representation;

        rhs._storage = _storage;
        rhs._representation = _representation;

        _storage = tmp._storage;
        _representation = tmp._representation;
    }

    bool has_value() const noexcept
    {
        switch (_representation)
        {
        case any_representation::Big:
            return _storage.big_storage.handler != nullptr;
        case any_representation::Small:
            return _storage.small_storage.handler != nullptr;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
    const std::type_info& type() const noexcept
    {
        if (has_value())
        {
            switch (_representation)
            {
                case any_representation::Big:
                    return *static_cast<const std::type_info*>(_storage.big_storage.handler->_type());
                case any_representation::Small:
                    return *static_cast<const std::type_info*>(_storage.small_storage.handler->_type());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return typeid(void);
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    T* get_val() noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(get_val_impl(any_is_small<T>{}));
    }

private:
    template<class T, class... Args>
    std::decay_t<T>& emplace_impl(std::true_type, Args&&... args) // any_is_trivial, any_is_small
    {
        // small any
        _storage.small_storage.handler = &any_small_obj<T>;
        Construct<T>(static_cast<void*>(&_storage.small_storage.storage), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        _representation = any_representation::Small;
        return reinterpret_cast<T&>(_storage.small_storage.storage);
    }

    template<class T, class... Args>
    std::decay_t<T>& emplace_impl(std::false_type, Args&&... args) // any_is_trivial, any_is_small
    {
        // big any
        _storage.big_storage.handler = &any_big_obj<T>;
        _storage.big_storage.storage = _aligned_malloc(sizeof(T), alignof(T));
        Construct<T>(_storage.big_storage.storage, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        _representation = any_representation::Big;
        return reinterpret_cast<T&>(_storage.big_storage.storage);
    }

    void* get_val_impl(std::true_type) noexcept
    {
        return (static_cast<void*>(&_storage.small_storage.storage));
    }

    void* get_val_impl(std::false_type) noexcept
    {
        return (_storage.big_storage.storage);
    }

    struct big_storage_t
    {
        void* storage;
        any_big* handler;
    };

    struct small_storage_t
    {
        typedef std::aligned_storage_t<small_space_size, std::alignment_of_v<void*>> internal_storage_t;
        internal_storage_t storage;
        any_small* handler;
    };

    struct storage
    {
        union
        {
            small_storage_t small_storage;
            big_storage_t big_storage;
        };

        std::type_info* _typeInfo;
    };

    storage _storage;
    any_representation _representation;
};

inline void swap(any& x, any& y) noexcept 
{
    x.swap(y);
}

template<class T, class... Args>
any make_any(Args&&... args)
{
    return any{std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

template<class T, class U, class... Args>
any make_any(std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args)
{
    return make_any(il, std::forward<Args>(args));
}

template<class T>
T any_cast(const any& operand)
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, const std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>&>);

    const auto storagePtr = any_cast<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>(&operand);

    if (!storagePtr)
    {
        throw bad_any_cast({});
    }

    return static_cast<T>(*storagePtr);
}

template<class T>
T any_cast(any& operand)
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>&>);

    const auto storagePtr = any_cast<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>(&operand);

    if (!storagePtr)
    {
        throw bad_any_cast({});
    }

    return static_cast<T>(*storagePtr);
}

template<class T>
T any_cast(any&& operand)
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<T, std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>);

    const auto storagePtr = any_cast<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>(&operand);

    if (!storagePtr)
    {
        throw bad_any_cast({});
    }

    return static_cast<T>(std::move(*storagePtr));
}

template<class T>
const T* any_cast(const any* operand) noexcept
{
    if (operand != nullptr && operand->type() == typeid(T))
    {
        return /*const_cast*/ operand->get_val<T>();
    }

    return nullptr;
}

template<class T>
T* any_cast(/*const*/ any* operand) noexcept
{
    if (operand != nullptr && operand->type() == typeid(T))
    {
        return /*const_cast*/ operand->get_val<T>();
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Edit: A more up-to-date version of this implenetantion can be found [here](https://github.com/TheSica/any/blob/master/any/any.h)

Answer (score 6):

You've got some issues with your perfect forwarding and move semantics. You wrote:

```
template<class T, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<VT, any>
                                   && std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>>>
any& operator=(T&& rhs)
{
    any tmp(rhs);
    tmp.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Here `T&& rhs` is a forwarding reference, so you ought to forward it:

```
    any tmp(std::forward<T>(rhs));
```

---

And again:

```
template<class T, typename VT = std::decay_t<T>, class... Args,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>
                                  && std::is_constructible_v<VT, Args...>>>
std::decay_t<T>& emplace(Args&&... args)
{
    reset();
    return emplace_impl<VT>(any_is_small<T>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Here you are correctly forwarding `Args&&... args`; but look closely at your `enable_if` condition! You're asking whether `VT` is constructible from `Args...`. But when you actually pass `args...` to `emplace_impl<VT>`, you end up trying to construct `VT` from `Args&&...`! So you should be testing

```
         class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<VT>
                               && std::is_constructible_v<VT, Args&&...>>>
```

instead. (And notice that I personally prefer `template<class>` over `template<typename>` — it means the same thing, it's just less to write and less to read.)

---

Since `enum class any_representation` is part of your struct layout and thus part of your ABI, you should add an explicit underlying type so that you know how many bytes it'll take up in your struct.

```
enum class any_representation : unsigned char { Small, Big };
```

---

```
template<class T, class... Args>
void Construct(void* destination, Args&&... args) noexcept
{
    new(destination) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

`noexcept`? Really? What if it throws?
This is a good argument to never put `noexcept` anywhere except on move-constructors (to avoid the vector pessimization) and perhaps `swap`. Certainly you should be very careful every time you apply it; don't just scatter it willy-nilly like `constexpr`!

---

```
template<class T>
any_big any_big_obj = { &any_big::Destroy<T>, &any_big::Copy<T>, &any_big::Type<T> };

template<class T>
any_small any_small_obj = { &any_small::Destroy<T>, &any_small::Copy<T>, &any_small::Move<T>, &any_small::Type<T> };
```

Why do you have two different layouts for these structs (`any_small` has 4 function pointers where `any_big` has only 3)? The whole point of `any` is that you're type-erasing everything about the original `VT` except for its affordances. If "small" VTs require different affordances than "big" VTs, you're probably doing something incorrect somewhere.

---

```
std::type_info* _typeInfo;
```

This field is completely unused, I think. Why is it here? (More importantly, how could you improve your workflow to avoid submitting code reviews for dead code?)

---

```
typedef std::aligned_storage_t<small_space_size, std::alignment_of_v<void*>> internal_storage_t;
internal_storage_t storage;
```

I strongly recommend against using `std::aligned_storage_t` in C++11-and-later; its behavior is [not portable](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/search?q=aligned_storage&type=Commits) from one library to the next. Instead, you can use C++11's built-in support for alignment:

```
alignas(void*) char storage[small_space_size];
```

---

```
inline void swap(any& x, any& y) noexcept 
{
    x.swap(y);
}
```

Prefer to use the Hidden Friend idiom here: make this function findable only via ADL.

---

```
void swap(any& rhs) noexcept
{
    any tmp;
    tmp._storage = rhs._storage;
    tmp._representation = rhs._representation;

    rhs._storage = _storage;
    rhs._representation = _representation;

    _storage = tmp._storage;
    _representation = tmp._representation;
}
```

First of all, if this code were correct, you should just be using `std::swap(_storage, rhs._storage); std::swap(_representation, rhs._representation);`, not writing out the three-step dance by hand.

However, this code is utterly wrong. Try it (on libstdc++ or libc++) with

```
any a1 = std::list<int>{1,2,3};
any a2 = std::list<int>{4,5,6};
a1.swap(a2);
std::list<int> r = any_cast<const std::list<int>&>(a1);
```

You can't just memswap the bytes of two `std::list`s and expect them to come through unscathed; `std::list` is not [trivially relocatable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGdfPextuAU). To move `a1`'s contents over into `a2`, and vice versa, you must at some point invoke `std::list`'s move-constructor. Your code never invokes the move-constructor, so I know it's wrong.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1A7HjR) seems to show that you've got problems elsewhere in the code, too. I haven't tried to track them down.

This goes to show: you should also write **unit tests** for your code, and test it, before submitting it for review!

---

```
return make_any(il, std::forward<Args>(args));
```

This line gives an error on Clang, because you forgot the `...` after `(args)`.

Comment: `is_constructible_v<T, Args...>` is identical to `is_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>` because `is_constructible` is defined in terms of `declval`.  Unless you are talking about incomplete types ...

Comment: Thank you for the review.
I'm not sure about the difference between `std::is_constructible_v<VT, Args&&...>>` and `std::is_constructible_v<VT, Args...>>` though.
I know that `Construct` should not have been marked as noexcept. My cppcore code analysis kept screaming I should mark it as noexcept for some reason and I did but it was the wrong call.
any_big doesn't have a `move` method because I work with pointers so in my mind I can just swap/assign the pointers that point to the allocated object on the heap.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I do change the `swap` method to work with `std::swap(storage...)` and and `std::swap(representation...)` your example works fine. You were right to say I shouldn't "three-step dance by hand". I don't see why I should (move) construct the objects in a `swap` operation though.

I do have unit tests for my code but perhaps these are not enough:
https://github.com/TheSica/any/blob/master/any/TestAny.cpp

I will work on fixing the errors/warnings that I get from different compilers.

Thank you again for your review!

Comment: @MariusT: Those look like a good start on tests! However, indeed, I don't see any tests of `swap` for non-trivially relocatable types. If you're on GCC/libstdc++, then even `std::string` (for a small string) would have exposed the problem with `swap`.

Comment: "`any_big` doesn't have a `move` method because I work with pointers so in my mind I can just swap/assign the pointers" — Right, what it means to "move" an `any_big` is pretty trivial. But you still have code somewhere that describes what you do to a `storage` when you need to "move" it, in the `any_big` case. You just chose to write that code inline rather than attach it to `void (*move)(void*, void*)`. If you attach it to `void (*move)(void*, void*)`, then your `big_handler` and `small_handler` get the same layout, so you're one step closer to removing that switch from your move-constructor.

Comment: I can confirm that any::swap with `std::swap(_storage, rhs._storage);` and `std::swap(_representation, rhs._representation);` instead of what I had, works with swapping `std:list<int>`, `std::string`, `std::list<TestObject>`. 
(https://github.com/TheSica/any/blob/master/any/TestAny.cpp#L405)

again, this is only tested on MSVC.
--
Also you have a very good point about getting rid of the switch and unifying everything!

Comment: Yes, MSVC's `std::list` is trivially relocatable. But try it with their `std::function` or `std::any`! See ["What library types are `trivially_relocatable` in practice?"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/20/p1144-what-types-are-relocatable/) (You might have to increase your `small_space_size` from 32 up to `sizeof(std::function<int()>`.) For more info including a walkthrough of the problem case (with `std::function` specifically), please watch the YouTube video linked from my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

1. Regarding your [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), you have to include the header [`<typeinfo>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo) before being allowed to use it.
2. In your `any_big` and `any_small`: Why does the function `static void* Type<T>()` return a `void*`? You could return a `const std::type_info&` instead
3. Your `any_big_obj` and `any_small_obj` are variables defined in the header-file. If you include your `any.h` in two cpp-files and instantiate the variable templates with the same type, you will get a linker error. Two avoid that, mark the variables as either const or inline (or both, which I suggest)

   ```
   inline const any_big any_big_obj = ...
   ```
4. In `any_small::Destroy`: The `if constexpr` check should be `!std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>`